# PHPStorm/WebStorm: how to ignore JS library in quick documentation

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

How can I set PHPStorm/Webstorm's integrated quick documentation to ignore a specific library/file?

For example, my project folder contains several revisions of a JS library (all with JSDoc comments).  I would like the quick documentation to ignore all but one.  Is this possible?

Also, two libraries might have the same class defined, and it would be extremely beneficial to at least be able to specify which library should be suppressed in the quick documentation list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set which js libraries will be used for any folder of your project in **Preferences->JavaScript Libraries->Usage Scope**